# pg_restore importing single table to a file

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-12, pg-restore

I have a backup in directory format taken with `pg_dump`.

When I try to export single table from this dump with the command:

```
pg_restore -Fd mydirectory -t sometable > table.sql
```

I get the error :

```
pg_restore: error: one of -d/--dbname and -f/--file must be specified.
```

When I read the document if no `-d` parameter passed `pg_restore` should print the output to stdout.

What I am  missing?

Comment: You are probably missing the fact that the restore source (in your case `mydirectory`) comes _after_ all options, not in between them.

Comment: If I use pg_restore  -t sometable -Fd mydirectory > table.sql  command I get the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to read the documentation for the version you are using.

Since v12, `-f -` is mandatory to get output to go to stdout.  Having that behavior be obtained just by omitting -d was considered to be confusing.  But since you want the output to go to a file, just name that file:

```
pg_restore -Fd mydirectory -t sometable -f table.sql
```

Comment: Thank you very much this solved my problem. My postgresql version is 12.